# how can I post data from input field without submit by ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I want to enter value, to input field so when I leave the input field by clcking out side from the input field I will run the ajax code and send the value input `dataString` to same file which in this case cald ajax.php.
Thanks

my code:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{



    var dataString;

$("valueforajax").mouseleave(function() {//when  we leave the field.
    alert('test it is mouseup ');
    dataString=$("#valueforajax").val();
    alert(dataString);
  if ("" = dataString){//it is mean that input field not empty
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
         url: "../../ajax.php",
             data: dataString,
             cache: false,
             success: function(html)
             {
             alert("There is submited sucsses");
             }
             });//ajax
        }//if
    });//mouseup
});//ready
```

ajax.php

```
<?php
    if  (isset($_POST['dataString'])){
        echo ("dataString not empty:= ".$_POST['dataString']);}
    ?>
    <html>
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./public/stylesheets/stylesheets.css"  >
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./public/js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./public/js/ajax.js"></script>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1255">
    <title>mange panel</title>
    </head>
    <body>

    <br>Type value for test in ajax<input id="valueforajax" type=text name='ajaxtest'>


    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 3):

You missed `#` sign in you selector

`$("valueforajax")` should be `$("#valueforajax")`.

also

`data: dataString` should be `data: 'dataString=' + dataString` OR `data: {"dataString": dataString}` because in your php code you're searching for

`$_POST['dataString']` i.e. for `dataString` key.

```
$("#valueforajax").blur(function() { // blur is perfect for what you searching

    dataString = $.trim(this.value); // you don't need $("#valueforajax").val(); 
                                     // here, this is enough

  if (dataString){  // checking for presence of value
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
         url: "../../ajax.php",
             data: 'dataString=' + dataString, // or {"dataString": dataString}
             cache: false,
             success: function(html) {
                alert("There is submited sucsses");
             }
          });
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to use blur instead of mouseleave.

A blur event occurs whenever you leave a form element.  It occurs when you hit TAB, click outside the field, change fields, etc....

mouseleave only occurs when your mouse literally leaves the element.

Answer (score 0):

The data must be an object (eg `{"dataString" : "test"}` ) or a string (eg `"dataString=test"`)